# MongoDB: Filter the data's based on the decimal length

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Am trying to write a query in mongodb to filter out the address based on the coordinates some coordinates lat,lon has 8(above 8) decimal points few have like around 4 to 6. I want to filter out the select the data's which has more than 7 decimal points.

Dummy Datas

```
Loc: {
coordinates:[55.55555,33.33333]
}

Loc: {
coordinates:[55.55555555,33.3333333]
}
```

Now like this i have at-least more than 50 data's i want to take the data's which decimal point length is above 7 like the 2nd dummy data which i have mentioned above. I tried with $where didn't worked out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is you MongoDB server version?

Comment: It is 3.4x @chridam